# Project Euler: #1 in Haskell implementation

Tags: haskell

For Project Euler Question #1, the shortest one-liner in GHCI is:

```
sum [3,6..9999] + sum [5,10..9999] - sum [15,30..9999]
```

I found this after I solved the problem is a much bloody way. However, since I am new to Haskell, I decide to see if I could take this and put it together as a set of function returning similar answer to any value of x (step value, i.e. '3' or '5' above] and y (length of the list).

I have the first function done here:

```
sumList :: (Enum a, Num a) => a -> a -> a
sumList a b = sum[a,a+a..b]
```

Next I was trying to take this function and do something such as `sumListTotals [3,5] 1000` for example from the question. This would all `sumList` for each item in the list then one subtract the duplicate numbers (i.e. [15,30..1000] using the example.

I am not looking for someone to actually solve it but to help me in pointing me in the proper direction.

I was attempting to use the `map` function something like below:

```
sumListTotals list = map f list
    where f = sumlist a b
```

But, I am unsure how to pull out the stuff from the list or if I do something like `sumListTotals ([3,5],1000)` or am I completely on the wrong track here?

Update per @user5402:

```
module Project1 where

import Data.List (union)

sumListTotals :: (Enum a, Eq a, Num a) => a -> a -> a -> a
sumListTotals a b c = sum $ union [a,(*2)a..c] [b,(*2)b..c]
```

Comment: For an algorithmic solution, have a look at [Data.List.union](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:union)

Comment: Um...that's a cool function. =) .. I'll post something soon since I finally have some free time.

Comment: I think using `union` is a more clean/clearer solution then using the `where` clause. Though, I am not sure how to read the type sig of the function. I cheated and used ghci with `:t` to generate the sig. :P

Comment: You'll understand the `Enum ...`, `Eq ...` and `Num ...` notation once you get around to type classes. Alternatively for the type signature of `sumListTotals` you could have just used `Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`. It's not as general, but it's also easier to figure out.

Comment: I knew about the "a" could be also "Int" =)

Comment: @flamusdiu Both the arguments to `union` are in order. Maybe not suitable for a one-liner, but using a function that takes advantage of the order would give better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track:

```
sumListTotals a b c = sum [a,a+a..c] + sum [b,b+b..c] - sum[m,m+m..c]
  where m = ...???...
```

I'll leave you to figure out the definition of `m` since that's really a number theory problem and not a Haskell programming problem.

Clearly for `a = 3, b = 5` `m` should be `15`. But what should `m` be for `a = 3, b = 3`?

Comment: I completely didn't realize you could the `where` clause like this. :P

Comment: I am going to accept this answer since this will work but for those looking at this solution: user5402's comment about using `Data.List.union` works much better in this solution.

Comment: Note that `union` takes quadratic time in the length of one of its arguments and so is not the most efficient way to implement this idea. Since both lists are sorted and don't contain duplicates, you just have to merge them which only takes linear time. You might try writing `merge :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]` where you assume the input lists are already sorted.